# Type error when subtracting one call to a function from another before assigning to a variable in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo

I am working in OpenERP 7 (hosted on a Windows 8 Server). I am trying to make what I would consider a simple change, to adjust the _product_qty_available variable so that it calls the _get_product_available_func method twice to give me the on hand less the outgoing. My modified code is:

> ```
> def _get_product_available_func(states, what):
>     def _product_available(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
>         return {}.fromkeys(ids, 0.0)
>     return _product_available
>
> _product_qty_available = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out')) - _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('out',))
> _product_virtual_available = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned','done'), ('in', 'out'))
> _product_outgoing_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('out',))
> _product_incoming_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('in',))
> _product_real_qty = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
> ```

My OpenERP server fails to start when I make this change with the following error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'

I feel confident this is a python problem, not an openerp problem, but I have not been able to determine a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
_get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
```

Apparently returns a function.  So you need to *invoke* it to get the result:

```
_get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))()
```

Note the extra parens on the end.  If you need to pass arguments to the function, put them there (Python will raise an exception if you need arguments but don't provide any).

If you need to return a function:

```
_product_qty_available = lambda a1,a2:
    _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))(a1,a2) -
    _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('out',))(a1,a2)
```

That's just an example if each functions takes two arguments.  The idea is to craft an anonymous function using `lambda` which can be called with two arguments (a1,a2) and which will in turn call your other functions.

Comment: The ultimate answer is I can't achieve my goal this way, because a function needs to be returned and not an integer, which is what I wanted to return. Nonetheless, thanks for the help!